# Getting this Error

Tags: magento2

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Mirasvit\SeoMarkup\Block\Rs\Product
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class abc\MirasvitExtended\Block\Rs\Product\Interceptor does not exist

Answer (score 0):

php bin/magento setup:di:compile should help. Otherwise you probably have some typo in namespaces or block names.

Answer (score 0):

Please Follow This namespace

**layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="footer">
            <block class="[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Timeline" name="twitterfeed-timeline" template="footer/timeline.phtml"></block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

and my block class in **vendor/[namespace]/[module]/Block/Timeline.php**

```
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Timeline extends Template
{

    /**
     * Timeline constructor.
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTweets()
    {
        // ---
    }
}
```